# Accept text string instead of element in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

When making a jQuery plugin, is it possible to accept a text string instead of an element?

For example, instead of
`$("#someelement").myPlugin();`:
`$('Some text string').myPlugin();`

Also, is it possible to allow multiple parameters?

For example, `$('Text  here', 'Another text').myPlugin();`

I have been researching, and `$()` seems to be used only for selecting DOM elements. However, it's not possible to not use it. When I tried my test function using just `$.myPlugin();` it didn't work.

Therefore, for this kind of thing should I just use a function? Are jQuery plugins only used when targeting a DOM element (ie. the `$("p").greenify();` example). Or is it acceptable to use them like a regular function with params?

Comment: Why would you want to wrap a 'text string' inside a jquery object? Don't use a plugin, use a function instead, see David's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery "plugins" are just prototypes on the jQuery object. So when calling the constructor like `$('text')` it actually "does" something with the argument `text` (jQuery will treat this as a selector).

If you just want to create a "plugin" for manipulating text, here a simple one for you:

```
myPlugin('Text here', 'Another text');
```

Or you can extend the String prototype if you fancy:

```
String.prototype.myPlugin = function(suffix) {
    return this+suffix
};

'mytext'.myPlugin('.com') // -> mytext.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, I decided to just use a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

you can design your plugin to accept a string as parameter...

and then use it on a jquery selection

```
$('#myid').myPlugin('some text');
```

or even just as a regular function

```
myPlugin('some text');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question - what do you want to do exactly?

If you want to call just the plugin without selecting a DOM node, most jquery extensions register themselves to $.fn:

`$.fn.my_pluginname`

some possibilities to call it on an element:

```
$('#my-css-id').myPlugin(); 
$('<div class="justCreatedNow">content</div>').appendTo('body').myPlugin();
```